# View webpage in Hebrew language

Tags: html, character-encoding, hebrew, html-encode

I have a website with few HTML pages. How can I display them in the Hebrew language?

What are the steps that I should follow to ensure it is viewed in different languages for different countries?

Thanks

Comment: the question isn't clear. Do you have translation of the web pages, or do you expect to be able to translate them automatically? do you want to automatically detect which language to present (according to country?) or do you want the user to choose? Are the pages static, or else how do you generate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quite helpful if this question is rewritten.

What I believe that you are trying to ask is how to detect the user's language.

You can do this through headers. Most browsers add on the BrowserLanguage header tag when you go to a page. [This is customized through the browser's properties]

If you are dealing with static HTML pages you would need to setup redirection with your server to display the language appropriate site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Be able to get content in that language (don't depend on automated translation services)
- Select a character encoding (UTF-8 is generally the best choice), see http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/
- Ensure your [editor saves using that encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications)
- Ensure your [server specifies that it is using that encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset)
- Ensure that nothing mangles the encoding between the editor and server (such as by being inserted into a database that is configured to use a different encoding)